# Get the Latest version of browsers

Tags: python, api

I was wondering, is there any API to use in order to get the latest version number of the browsers. (Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari)
I have tried the web scraping methods in python in order to get the stable versions of each browser from Wikipedia. However, I am looking for a more efficient way to check the client browser.
I would appreciate it if someone helps me with this issue.

Comment: I know that. I just need an API to List each stable browser version with OS and etc.
All I want to do is to check the browser version for my authorization steps. @jsotola

Answer (score 1):

Check out "updatemybrowser.org":

> https://updatemybrowser.org/
>
> **Latest browsers:**
>
> - Chrome 102
> - Safari 15.5
> - Edge 102
> - Firefox 101
> - Internet Explorer 11
> - Opera 86

See also: https://updatemybrowser.org/about/docs

Answer (score 0):

Browsers usually set their version in the HTTP `User-Agent` header. You could check that against the list of versions your application supports.

Comment: Thanks. But, I know I can check it with the user-agent header. I just need a source to get the list of valid versions for the browser in order to check the validation.